# org-mac-iCal not working

Tags: org-mode, ical

I am trying to setup `org-mac-iCal` See https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-mac-iCal.html.

Nothing happens when Emacs loads. Even when I run the specific function `org-mac-iCal`, nothing happens still.

My configuration:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(require 'org)
(require 'org-mac-iCal)
(add-to-list 'org-modules 'org-mac-iCal)
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("I" "Import diary from iCal" agenda ""
         ((org-agenda-mode-hook
           (lambda ()
             (org-mac-iCal)))))))
#+END_SRC
```

The diary file remains empty. Incidentally, if the diary does not exist, this complains about that, but that's not really an issue.

My iCalendar has many calendars. They are all *checked*, per the documentation in the link above.

UPDATE: This package might be just too old?

Comment: do you evaluate those code blocks?

Comment: @manandearth yes of course. This is part of my configuration (using org-mode style configuration).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it turns out that all one has to fix is the version that the `org-mac-iCal` expects (namely, just add your Mac version directly in this line: https://github.com/Fuco1/org-mode/blob/master/contrib/lisp/org-mac-iCal.el#L101).

The rest works beautifully. Be sure to read the docs: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-mac-iCal.html.